# How to check username and password is valid or not in existing database with PasswordHash and SecurityStamp?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt, password-hash

I am new in **Asp.Net Core**. I have implemented **JWT Bearer Token Based Authentication and Authorization**. Token is generated successfully but in the existing database, **AspNetUser** table has password in encrypted format with **PasswordHash** and **SecurityStamp** column. So, how can i check the username and password from the database?

Please find the below code of partial Startup class for generating token :

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();


        ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

and

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // The secret key every token will be signed with.
    // Keep this safe on the server!
    private static readonly string secretKey = "mysupersecret_secretkey!123";

    private void ConfigureAuth(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

        app.UseSimpleTokenProvider(new TokenProviderOptions
        {
            Path = "/api/token",
            Audience = "ExampleAudience",
            Issuer = "ExampleIssuer",
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
            IdentityResolver = GetIdentity
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,

            // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            CookieName = "access_token",
            TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(
                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                tokenValidationParameters)
        });
    }

    private Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(string username, string password)
    {
        // Here i want to match username and password with passwordHash and SecurityStamp
        if (username == "TEST" && password == "TEST123")
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(username, "Token"), new Claim[] { }));
        }

        // Credentials are invalid, or account doesn't exist
        return Task.FromResult<ClaimsIdentity>(null);
    }
}
```

In above code, i am checking the username and password with hard coded value but i need to do the same thing by using the existing database with AspNetUser table(autocreated by MVC5)

Thanks

Comment: What has jwt got to do with it? Seems not relevant to this question.

Comment: JWT for generating the Token to return after verifying the email and password

Comment: But you have no problem with generating the token, so why mention it? Anyways, it helps if you add information, like what (packages) did you use to implement security? Did you implement a usermanager? Can you show some (relevant) code?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg  ihave updated the question please check

Comment: i have not implement usermanager

Comment: You'll need to add a storage provider. Please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers

Answer (score 1):

Identity Core has a [PasswordHasher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher(v=vs.108).aspx) that you can leverage. Just as an example, you can do as shown below:

```
//Initialize it
var _passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
```

Find the user you want to verify:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
```

Then, you can verify the user like:

```
if (user == null || _passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, request.Password) != PasswordVerificationResult.Success)            
{
return BadRequest();
}
```

If it passes this section, you can then generate the token:

```
var token = await GetJwtSecurityToken(user);
```

*GetJwtSecurityToken()* is just my own function with token generation token, but I understand you've already done it on your end.

I don't understand why SO is not formatting my code.

Comment: It is showing object reference is not set error on this line `{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'`.. i think it's related to usermanager implementation